# Como fazer uma promise retornar um valor depois de 2 segundos

Tags: javascript, promises

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt('Digite sua idade: '), 10);

function verificar(age){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if(age > 18){
            resolve()
        }else{
            reject()
        }
    })
}

verificar()
.then(
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            console.log('Maior de 18 anos')
        },2000
    )
    
)
.catch(
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            console.log('Menor de 18 anos')
        },2000
    )
)
```

O problema é que ele dá um erro no console e retorna 2 strings. Como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer simular um delay na sua promise, você deveria colocar o `setTimeout` dentro da sua promise, antes de invocar `resolve()`

Mas por que seu código não funciona? Dentro de `then` e `catch`, você deveria declarar uma função de callback, mas você não está declarando uma função, você está **invocando** uma função (`setTimeout`). A função `setTimeout` retorna um número inteiro para o `then`, que é basicamente um identificador para esse timeout, e então como o `then` recebe um número ao invés de receber uma função, ele te devolve um erro.

Como seu código deveria estar:

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt('Digite sua idade: '), 10);

function verificar(age){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(age >= 18){
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject()
            }
        }, 2000)
    })
}

verificar(age)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Maior de 18 anos')
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log('Menor de 18 anos')
    })
```

Ou então usando algumas arrow functions:

```js
const age = parseInt(prompt('Digite sua idade: '), 10)

function verificar(age) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        setTimeout(() => age >= 18 ? resolve() : reject(), 2000)
    )
}

verificar(age)
    .then(() => console.log('Maior de 18 anos'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Menor de 18 anos'))
```